# Why do I get "/bin/ld: cannot find -lws2_32" when making windows binary in RHEL?

Tags: gcc, makefile, compiler-errors, mingw, mingw32

I want to compile the ASCO optimization software using supplied Makefile.win.
(https://asco.sourceforge.net/downloads.html)

However, I am always getting the "/bin/ld: cannot find -lws2_32" error

I installed mingw64-gcc, mingw32-gcc at my RHEL8 machine. And still get the same.

The contents of Makefile.win are as follows

```
#
CC = gcc
CC_MPI = <FULL_PATH_TO_MPICH>/bin/mpicc
CFLAGS = -Os


#
all: asco asco-test alter log monte postp

asco-test:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -DDEBUG -DASCO -o asco-test.exe auxfunc.c auxfunc_alter.c auxfunc_monte.c auxfunc_measurefromlis.c rfmodule.c initialize.c errfunc.c evaluate.c asco-test.c -lm -lws2_32

asco:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -DASCO -o asco.exe auxfunc.c auxfunc_alter.c auxfunc_monte.c auxfunc_measurefromlis.c rfmodule.c initialize.c errfunc.c evaluate.c de36.c hooke.c nmlatest.c asco.c -lm -lws2_32

asco-mpi:
    $(CC_MPI) $(CFLAGS) -DASCO -DMPI -o asco-mpi.exe auxfunc.c auxfunc_alter.c auxfunc_monte.c auxfunc_measurefromlis.c rfmodule.c initialize.c errfunc.c evaluate.c de36.c hooke.c nmlatest.c asco.c -lm -lws2_32

alter::
    make -C tools/alter/ -f Makefile.win32

log::
    make -C tools/log/ -f Makefile.win32

monte::
    make -C tools/monte/ -f Makefile.win32

postp::
    make -C tools/postp/ -f Makefile.win32

clean::
    rm -f asco.exe asco-test.exe
    rm -f tols/alter/alter.exe
    rm -f tools/log/log.exe
    rm -f tools/monte/monte.exe
    rm -f tools/postp/postp.exe
```

Comment: `CC = gcc` is probably not the gcc of mingw64-gcc.

Comment: ah. didn't know the binary is different. will try tomorrow. thanks!

Comment: it was "i686-w64-mingw32-gcc" to be precise, and there are a bunch of references to other Makefile.win.
So when I replaced the gcc everywhere and called mingw-make, I got two main EXEs. (btw, it refuses compilling when linux binaries are in the same folder).
But there are more errors:

Comment: ```make -C tools/alter/ -f Makefile.win32
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/user/src/ASCO-0.4.11/tools/alter'
i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -Os -o alter.exe ../auxfunc/auxfunc.o auxfunc_alter.o alter.c -lm -lws2_32
../auxfunc/auxfunc.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [Makefile.win32:10: alter] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/user/src/ASCO-0.4.11/tools/alter'
make: *** [Makefile.win32:20: alter] Error 2
```
What is that?

Comment: auxfunc.o is refered in another makefile in /tools/alter
```#
CC = i686-w64-mingw32-gcc
CFLAGS = -Os


#
all: ../auxfunc/auxfunc.o auxfunc_alter.o alter

alter:
 $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o alter.exe ../auxfunc/auxfunc.o auxfunc_alter.o alter.c -lm -lws2_32
 strip alter.exe

clean::
 rm -f *.o
 rm alter.exe```

Comment: Did you do a `make clean` to remove all previously built Linux executables/objects?

Comment: no. I did not know it is necessary. But I just deleted the folder and unpacked the tar clean again. The the issue with the ".o" file happens from the clean unpacked source.